# What story has the protagonist stranded on a planet in a cave with a predator?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have read this short story in several anthologies and I don't know when it was published.

The protagonist is stranded on a planet that is hostile to human life. He lives in a cave with a powerful predator that doesn't eat humans (I think). He doesn't interact with the predator in any way.

There are a few scenes of him getting food and avoiding hostile creatures.

At the end a tourist from the spaceport on the planet comes along in some kind of flying device to gawk, and the protagonist hijacks the vehicle and heads back to the spaceport where it's revealed that he was hijacked much the same way (it wasn't a time travel story).

Comment: Do you remember how far back you first read it or the genders of the characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is "Contrast" (Analog, 1964) by Christopher Anvil.   This was published as part of the Interstellar Patrol II.

The following is a description of the "Trouble with Colonies" series of short stories included in this book.  Perhaps some of the other titles/descriptions will also match up with you memories to confirm this is the anthology about which you were writing.

Good luck.

[Amazon Description - Short Story Titles and Descriptions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416520996)

The last seven tales in this collection are about the Troubles With Colonies. "The Operator" (Analog, 1971) puts the acting leader of a colony figuratively between a den of pack-bears and a shipload of neobarbarians, with some desirable females as the prize. "While the North Wind Blows" (Amazing, 1978) continues the previous story, only now the warm spell has led to an influx of giant flit birds and the awakening of the flame throwing slags. "Leverage" (Astounding, 1959) tells of a planet where the lifeforms cooperate much more vigorously than expected. "The Sieve" (Astounding, 1959) relates a tale of a new colony with too many uncooperative druggies. "Mating Problems" (Astounding, 1959) reveals one way of canceling out difficulties. "Hunger" (Analog, 1964) suggests that material goods and self-control is not enough. **"Contrast" (Analog, 1964) explains a service provided to jaded citizens by one group of colonists.**

Comment: thats the one, much obliged.